# Relative elevations of the bases for Falcon and Starship pad at LC-39A

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship

The NASA environmental report of August 2019 (https://netspublic.grc.nasa.gov/main/20190801_Final_DRAFT_EA_SpaceX_Starship.pdf) provides a 2D view of of the planned changes to 39A for Starship. A launch animation, provided by SpaceX shows the SuperHeavy/Starship stack on a raised platform, but lacks any existing 39A components to derive a relative height reference. (

).

[image: Important image from the PDF]

Given the distance between the old and new towers and the need to share infrastructure, has anyone heard if the bases of the rockets are at the same height?

Comment: Since they are building a fairly large launch mount starting at a lower level, it is unclear how tall it is going to be when complete and thus the relative elevations when complete. May take time to answer this one.